How to find the eigenvalues of this matrix?
I'm reading "A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations" by Arieh Iserle. It solves Poisson's equation $\nabla^2 u=f(x,y), (x,y)\in\Omega=[0,1]\times [0,1]$  by the five-point formula.
Begin from the origin, $f_{k, \ell}=$ $f\left(x_0+k \Delta x, y_0+\ell \Delta x\right)$, we can get five-point difference formula:
$$
u_{k-1, \ell}+u_{k+1, \ell}+u_{k, \ell-1}+u_{k, \ell+1}-4 u_{k, \ell}=(\Delta x)^2 f_{k, \ell}
$$
Divide the border into $m+1$ segments at equal intervals

Use the difference formula for interior points, the boundary points are known as initial values. Interior points are $u_{1,1}\cdots,u_{1,m}\cdots,u_{m,1},\cdots,u_{m,m}$. Let $u=[u_{1,1},\cdots,u_{m,m}]'$, we can obtain a system of $m^2$-element linear equations
$$Au=b.$$
My question is how to determine the shape of this matrix and its eigenvalues. Here is the explanation from the book, but I don't know how it works. I tried to write a matrix of order 9, but I still have trouble spotting the pattern.


Can someone give me a hint? Thank you very much！

One way to think of this is to recall how one associates a matrix to a linear map: if $V$ is a vector space and $\alpha \colon V \to V$ a linear map, then given a basis $B$ of $V$, the linear map $\alpha$ is completely determined by its action on $B$, that is, by the vectors $\{\alpha(b): b \in B\}$, and these vectors are determined by their coordinates with respect to the basis $B$, that is, for each $c \in B$ we may write $\alpha(c) = \sum_{b \in B} a_{b,c} b$ for unique scalars $a_{b,c}$, and thus the array $(a_{b,c})_{b,c \in B}$ completely determines $\alpha$. Indeed if $v \in V$ we may write $v$ uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$, say $v =\sum_{c \in B} \lambda_c.c$ and then
$$
\alpha(v) = \sum_{c\in B}\lambda_c \alpha(c)  = \sum_{c \in B} \lambda_c\left(\sum_{b \in B} a_{b,c} b\right) = \sum_{b \in B}\left(\sum_{c \in B} a_{b,c}\lambda_c\right)b
$$
Now all of the above is completely standard except for the fact that one normally writes $B= \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and labels the scalars giving the coordinate of $\alpha(e_i)$ as $a_{ij}$ rather than $a_{e_i,e_j}$. What that notation does, however, is tacitly impose an ordering of the basis elements which is unnecessary from the point of view of calculating the action of $\alpha$ in terms of the coordinate system given by the choice of basis $B$.
To be more specific, in the OP, the interior points of the grid give an $m^2$-dimensional vector space, with a natural basis $\{1_{i,j}: 1 \leq i,j \leq m\}$ given by the functions which are $1$ at a single grid point $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else. The goal is to find solutions to $(\Delta_x)^2(\mathbf u) =0$ where $\mathbf u = (u_{i,j})$ corresponds to the function $\sum_{i,j=1}^m u_{i,j}1_{i,j}$. Now $(\Delta_x)^2$ is a linear map, and its action on the basis $1_{ij}$ is given by the five-point difference formulae,
$$
(\Delta_x)^2(1_{ij}) = 1_{i-1,j}+1_{i,j-1}+1_{i+1,j}+1_{i,j+1}-41_{ij}
$$
Taking the $4m$ boundary points as input data the 5-point difference formulae then give a system of $m^2$ inhomogenous linear equations. To write the data in the form of a conventional matrix, one would have to impose a total order on the basis $\{1_{i,j}: 1 \leq i,j \leq m\}$, but Iserle points out that there is no need to -- one can just as well work with the unordered array labelled by pairs $(i,j),(i',j')$. The matrix/array $(a_{(ij),(i'j')})$ of $(\Delta_x)^2$ is symmetric because $a_{(ij),(i'j')}$ is $-4$ on the diagonal, $i.e.$ where $(ij) =(i'j')$ and $1$ when $|i-i'|+|j-j'|=1$ and zero otherwise.
Notice that this description shows immediately that $a_{(ij),(i'j')} = a_{(i'j'),(ij)}$ so that the matrix/array of $(\Delta_x)^2$ is symmetric. It follows that it is orthogonally diagonalizable.
It follows that if one imposes the boundary condition that $u$ vanishes at all boundary nodes and seek a function satisfying those boundary conditions with $(\Delta_x)^2(\mathbf u) = \lambda\mathbf u$ then $\mathbf u$ must be an eigenvector for $(\Delta_x)^2$ (or equivalently $A= (a_{(ij),(i'j')})$). The choice of the function $u_{kl} = \sin(\frac{k\alpha}{m+1})\sin(\frac{l\beta}{m+1})$ is really motivated by the fact that the identity
$$
\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b) = 2\sin(a)\cos(b)
$$
shows that, if we define, for each $\alpha \in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$ a sequence $\mathbf s_\alpha :=(\sin(\frac{k\alpha}{m+1}))_{k=0}^m = (s_{\alpha,k})_{k=0}^m$ then the $\mathbf s_{\alpha}$ satisfy $s_{\alpha,0} = s_{\alpha,m}=0$ and $s_{\alpha,k+1}+s_{\alpha,k-1} - 2s_{\alpha,k}= 2(\cos(\frac{\alpha}{m+1})-1)s_{\alpha,k}$
